# Kafka JDBC Sink Connector, insert values in batches

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I receive a lot of the messages (by http-protocol) per second (50000 - 100000) and want to save them to PostgreSql. I decided to use Kafka JDBC Sink for this purpose.

The messages are saved to database by one record, not in batches. I want to insert records in PostgreSQL in batches with size 500-1000 records.

I found some answers on this problem in issue: [How to use batch.size?](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/290)

I tried to use related options in configuration, but it seems that they no have any effect.

My Kafka JDBC Sink PostgreSql configuration (`etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/postgres.properties`):

```
name=test-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=3

# The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors like this one
topics=jsonb_pkgs

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test?currentSchema=test
auto.create=false
auto.evolve=false

insert.mode=insert
connection.user=postgres
table.name.format=${topic}

connection.password=pwd

batch.size=500
# based on 500*3000byte message size
fetch.min.bytes=1500000
fetch.wait.max.ms=1500
max.poll.records=4000
```

I also added options to `connect-distributed.properties`:

```
consumer.fetch.min.bytes=1500000
consumer.fetch.wait.max.ms=1500
```

Although each a partition gets more than 1000 records per second, records are saved to PostgreSQL by one.

**Edit: consumer options were added in other file with correct names**

I also added options to `etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties`:

```
# based on 500*3000 byte message size
consumer.fetch.min.bytes=1500000
consumer.fetch.wait.max.ms=1500
consumer.max.poll.records=4000
```

Comment: It should be `consumer.max.poll.records`, by the way

Comment: I tried to change max.poll.records -> consumer.max.poll.records, but receive the same result.

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying, that is the correct property name. In any case, records ought to be sent in individual queries, I'm not sure there are transactions rules around batches

Comment: is the consumer.max.pool.records defined for each individual connector? or is this a cental Kafka configuration?

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry for the confusion but are you sure we need to append the consumer. to the max.poll.records ? it seems everywhere I find it is without consumer.

Comment: In Kafka Connect you do, yes @Miguel

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you, I was looking at the code and could not figure it out, is this managed by the WorkerSinkTask? Because I only found them in the ConsumerConfig
For example would it work that way for all the https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs ?
Do I find that information somewhere in the documentation I would really like to find that.

Comment: @OneCricketeer by the way not sure you are there but I had asked this question in confluent slack channel
https://confluentcommunity.slack.com/archives/C49L0V3L7/p1621585358118700
I believe you and I'm trying to use it with "consumer." but would be really cool to have this information somewhere in the docs (maybe it is and I just did not look properly)

Comment: @Miguel Wrong section. Search for "the same parameters can be used but need to be prefixed with producer. and consumer. respectively"

Answer (score 5):

I realised that I misunderstood the documentation. The records are inserted in database one by one. The count of the records inserted in one transaction depends on `batch.size` and `consumer.max.poll.records`. I expected that the batch insert was implemented the other way. I would like to have an option to insert records like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (First, Last)
VALUES
    ('Fred', 'Smith'),
    ('John', 'Smith'),
    ('Michael', 'Smith'),
    ('Robert', 'Smith');
```

But that seems impossible.